# create a temporary variable in vue js template

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have the following vue template

```
<div v-for="(v, k, i) in subs" :key="index">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Barang</th>
                <th>Satuan</th>
                <th>Jumlah</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr v-for="j in ranges[k]">
                <td><Select2 :options="goods" @change="fill_units(i)" /></td>
                <td><Select2 ref="units" :options="[]" /> </td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button @click="ranges[k]++">Add row</button>
</div>
```

and the data

```
data(){
    return {
        ranges: {
            makanan: 1,
            minuman: 1,
            dll: 1
        }
        subs: {
            makanan: 'Makanan',
            minuman: 'Minuman',
            dll: 'Dan lain-lain'
        }
    }
}
```

what I want is, when first `Select2` element change its value, this will trigger the next `Select2` element to fill its options based on it's `ref`. the problem is, `i` is not the correct index for the next `Select2`, since there might be more row added by the user. I think temporary variable that can hold the total rows on each table can solve the problem, but I don't know how to make that variable inside the template.

equivalent in vanilaJS loop, look like this

```
let total_rows = 0;
for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    for(let j = 0; j < 5; j++){
        total_rows++; // i need this variable
        fill_units(total_rows);
    }
}
```

I am so sorry if my question isn't clear enough

edit: add select2 code

```
fill_units(value, i){
    const types = this.goods.filter(type => type.id == value);
    if(types.length > 0){
        const units = types[0].units;

        // delete all previous selections
        this.$refs.units[i].select2.empty();

        // append new selections
        this.$refs.units[i].select2.append(`<option value="">Pilih Unit</option>`);
        units.forEach(unit => {
            this.$refs.units[i].select2.append(`<option value="${unit.id}">${unit.name}</option>`);
        })

        // this.$refs.units[i].select2.trigger('change');
    }

}
```

Comment: Please show the `Select2` code. I think you just need to pass the proper value from that component, when you fire the `change` event, and access from outside using _$event_, instead of the _i_.

Comment: I ment the `Select2` component, if it is code you have access to.

Comment: nope, that's a plugin. https://www.npmjs.com/package/v-select2-component